# Bubble chart without axis with labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, bubble-chart

I have the following data frame:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(text = structure(c(9L, 10L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 1L, 
11L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 5L, NA, 6L, 13L, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, 3L
), .Label = c("add ", "change ", "clarify", "correct", "correct ", 
"delete", "embed", "follow", "name ", "remove", "remove ", "specifiy ", 
"update"), class = "factor"), ID = c(1052330L, 915045L, 931207L, 
 572099L, 926845L, 510057L, 927946L, 490640L, 928498L, 893872L, 
 956074L, 627059L, 508649L, 508657L, 1009304L, 493138L, 955579L, 
 144052L, 1011166L, 151059L, 930992L, 913074L)), .Names = c("text", 
 "ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

I would like to have a bubble chart for my df with circles labeling with each verb in the text column and also the number of IDs that are related to each verb in the text column. This is the code I have for the circles but I don't know how to do the labeling:

```
> library(packcircles)
> library(ggplot2)
> packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(df)
> dat.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(packing)
> ggplot(data = dat.gg) +geom_polygon(aes(x, y, group = id, fill =  factor(id)), colour = "black",show.legend = FALSE) +scale_y_reverse() +coord_equal()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a `data.frame` for your labels with the appropriate x and y coordinate and use `geom_text`

```
library(ggplot2)
packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(df)
dat.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(packing)
cbind(df, packing) -> new_df
ggplot(data = dat.gg) +geom_polygon(aes(x, y, group = id, fill =  factor(id)), colour = "black",show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_reverse() +coord_equal() +geom_text(data = new_df, aes(x, y,label = text))
```

[image]

For the `Text` and `ID`, you can do:

```
new_df$text2 <- paste0(new_df$text,"\n",new_df$ID)
ggplot(data = dat.gg) +geom_polygon(aes(x, y, group = id, fill =  factor(id)), colour = "black",show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_reverse() +coord_equal() +geom_text(data = new_df, aes(x, y,label = text2))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry theres a mistake in my code generatng the circles, I have to get 13 circles which is the number of levels(df$text), you know how should I correct this?@Jrakru56

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you referring to the fact that there are more than 1 circles with the same name?

Comment: exactly, there should be 13 circles in the chart @Jrakru56

Comment: Looking at `df`, there are 22 rows with duplicating `text` names.  You might be missing an aggregating step such as counting the number of occurrences of each `text`.  `circleProgressiveLayout` was not provided with any parameters for the size of the circles. Does this make sense?